# existe alguna forma de abrir un txt con python

Tags: python, tkinter, txt

a ver para que se me entienda necesito abri un archivo de texto pero cuando me refiero a abrirlo lo que digo es ejecutarlo.se que existe esto pero esto no no es lo que yo quiero

```
archivo = open("hello.txt", “w”)
archivo.write("Hola") 
archivo.close()
```

yo lo que quiero es abrir el archivo como si estubiera dandole  2 click,,,como por ejemplo cuando quiero ejecutar un .mp3,,yo lo que deseo es ejecutar el txt y que se me abra

Comment: Por partes, ni un mp3 ni un txt son ejecutables, al hacer doble click lo que haces es abrir un programa predeterminado por el sistema operativo que maneja ese tipo de archivos, un reproductor de música o un editor de texto respectivamente. No me queda muy claro lo que quieres, una cosa es  mostrar el contenido de un archivo en una app de tkinter (crear un editor de texto con Python y tkinter, un "block de notas") y otra es que al hacer doble click se use una aplicación de Python para manejar el archivo, ésto último es cosa de tu sistema operativo de turno, debes asociar los txt con la app.

Comment: lo que quiero es que cuando yo apriete un boton predefinido en una aplicacion que tengo en tkinter este me abra un archivo de texto que tengo en cierta direccion en pc,lo que pregunto es si existe alguna librearia para abrir archivos de texto como esxisten librerias para reproducir mp3,realmente lo que necesito es editar ese rchivo de texto,,pero lo que quiero es abrirlo mediante el boton para luego yo editarlo manualmente

Comment: ¿Pero quieres editarlo en la propia app o en el editor predeterminado del sistema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer así:

```
import os
os.system("notepad.exe file.txt")
```

O como un subproceso:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['notepad.exe', 'file.txt'])
```

Comment: Una observación, `subprocess.call` está obsoleto actualmente (se mantiene solo por retrocompatibilidad) y `os.system` en la practica también dado que es una API muy limitada y básica que permite un control casi nulo del subproceso, en Python >= 3.5 se debe usar [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) como norma general.